# jquery newb, trouble understanding selectors and indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some trouble understanding how selectors and indexes work in JQuery.  I was hoping to write some functions that manipulate html elements based on class attributes, and I realized that when I try to use the index() method or prevAll().length to get the position of an element within a set of elements, I'm not always getting the expected result.

Below, I have a piece of jquery code that does something for everything with the class .element_list, and then within that something for everything with the class .element_list_item.  I have two .element_lists, A and B, and all this does is alert me the indexes of the .element_list_items.  For list A, the indexes come back as 0 and 1, as expected.  In list B, I added a thead element with no class attribute, so in my mind it shouldn't be grabbed by my jquery code, but the two .element_list_items come back with indexes of 1 and 2, instead of 0 and 1 as expected.

Why is that?  My selector is looking for elements wtih the class .element_list_item and a class equal to the contain .element_list's ID, so why would the addition of the thead affect the positions of the tbodies?

Any help understanding this is appreciated.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
$('.element_list').each(function()
{
    var list_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var first_item_id = $(this).find('.' + list_id + '.element_list_item:eq(0)').attr('id');

    alert('List and first list item:  ' + list_id + ' - ' + first_item_id);        

    $(this).find('.' + list_id + '.element_list_item').each(function()
    {
        var list_item_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var index = $(this).prevAll().length;

        alert('List item and its index:  ' + list_item_id + ' - ' + index);
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" enableviewstate="true">
<br />
<br />
<table class="table_noborder">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>List A</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="list_A" class="element_list">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody id="list_A_item0" class="element_list_item list_A">
                        <tr>
                            <td>First Item</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody id="list_A_item1" class="element_list_item list_A">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Second Item</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>List B</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="list_B" class="element_list">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Header</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="list_B_item0" class="element_list_item list_B">
                        <tr>
                            <td>First Item</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody id="list_B_item1" class="element_list_item list_B">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Second Item</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well see http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/ I am thinking prevAll('.element_list') might help. I have never used this before so go ahead and test it out.

Comment: You have $(this).find('.' + list_id + '.element_list_item') but you're not using the .element_list_item class in your markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) with no arguments will get it's index compared to all siblings.  You can pass in a selector to for it to check in comparison with the collection

so

```
$('#list_B_item0').index() // will return 1 since thead(it's prev sibling) is in index 0
```

but

```
$('#list_B_item0').index('.element_list_item.list_B') //  returns 0 since it will compare it's index with the collection
```

It can also be done the other way

```
$('.element_list_item.list_B').index('#list_B_item0') // returns 0
```

Comment: You have solved my problem.  Thanks for helping me understand how these methods work.